# jsf h:messages/ h:message for specific clientId

Tags: jsf, facelets, message

I would like to display different FacesMessages with programmatically set clientIds. In my view I used

```
<h:outputText value="warnMessages #{facesContext.getMessageList('warnMessages')}" />
<h:outputText value="validationMessages #{facesContext.getMessageList('validationMessages')}" />
```

for debugging. The messages are all there. But...

```
<h:messages for="warnMessages"  />
<h:message for="warnMessages"  />
```

doesn't display anything. Only

```
<h:messages />
```

works. But I would like to have different message-boxes displayed together. How can I do that? Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 5):

It look like that you're abusing client IDs to separate custom/global messages from normal validation messages.

You shouldn't do that. If you want to display a custom/global message, just don't specify any client ID. I.e., set it to `null`.

```
context.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
```

This way they will all appear in

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

And use the renmant of the messages the usual way.

```
<h:inputText id="foo" required="true" />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

or

```
<h:messages globalOnly="false" />
```

Comment: I have validations which exeed single field validation. I don't use JSF or Bean Validation but custom ones. Furthermore I would like to show warnMessages, errorMessages, workflowMessages, also in combination. All FacesMessages are added programatically. It seems that I am not able to directly add such messages to h:message(s) components. Right? One single h:messages with globalOnly="true" is not sufficient. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `h:messages` display all messages, also those with missing client id. So the `for` attribute is not allowed.

The `for` attribute in `h:message` must match the `id` attribute of another component: in your example you have to set `id="warnMessages"` in whatever `h:inputText` you want.

Comment: Thank you, I added <h:outputText value="" id="warnMessages" /> Still the 'programmatically' added FacesMessages don't show up

Comment: `input`, not `output`. The validation messages are to be associated with input components.

Comment: I used <h:inputText value="something" id="warnMessages" /> but the <h:message> component still doesn't show anything.

Comment: The problem could be the id. On Java side, you must use the clientId, that is not always the same id you specified in the page source.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541245/an-efficient-way-to-compute-a-uicomponent-clientid

Comment: @PierLuigi you say "...the `for` attribute is not allowed." The Facelets Tag Documentation lists a `for` attr for the `h:messages` tag. Furthermore, I've tried it, and the `h:messages` tag works with the `for` attr as expected. Am I missing, or misunderstanding something? If using `h:message` and there is more than one message associated with an id, then only the first message gets rendered...but using `h:messages`, all the messages get rendered with the associated HTML element. If I'm wrong on something, please explain.

Answer (score -1):

Adding custom messages to JSF pages is not that difficult. But you will have to do some effort to do all the required stuff.

e.g.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.warnMessages}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.infoMessages}" />
```

and in bean class

```
...
public class Bean {
...
    public String warnMessages() {
      // concatenate (and add new lines to) all the WARNING string messages, with
      // html+css formatting, together and
      return warnings;
    }
    public String infoMessages() {
      // concatenate (and add new lines to) all the INFO string messages, with
      // html+css formatting, together and
      return infos;
    }
}
```

Also remember to update the output text messages using ajax upon some event, which will call the bean's `warnMessages()` and `infoMessages()` methods.