# rich:message not showing after a4j event

Tags: richfaces, seam, ajax4jsf

I have the following xhtml code in my Seam project:

```
<rich:column style="text-align:right">
    <h:inputText id="txtPercReqAmount" maxlength="6" style="width:75px;text-align:right;" value="#{pib.reservedPercentage}">
        <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" action="#{requestForm.onReservedPercentageChange(pib)}" reRender="txtReqAmount,txtBudget,msgPercReqAmount"/>
    </h:inputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column width="250px" style="text-align:left">
    <rich:message id="msgPercReqAmount" for="txtPercReqAmount" styleClass="messagesingle" errorClass="errormsg" infoClass="infomsg" warnClass="warnmsg">
        <f:facet name="errorMarker"><h:graphicImage url="/img/msgerror.png"/></f:facet>
    </rich:message>
</rich:column>
```

and I make some validation in the "onchange" event of the inputText. If the validation fails, I want to write the error message in the `<rich:message>` column.
Here is the java code of my backing bean event:

```
public void onReservedPercentageChange(ProcessInstanceBudget pib) {
    BigDecimal arg2 = pib.getReservedPercentage();
    BigDecimal ra;
    try
    {
        if (arg2 instanceof BigDecimal)
            ra = (BigDecimal) arg2;
        else
            ra = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException cce)
    {
        facesMessages.add(Severity.ERROR, "The allocation request isn't valid!");
        return;
    }

    if (ra.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 || ra.compareTo(new BigDecimal(100.0)) > 0) {
        facesMessages.add(Severity.ERROR, "Allocation percentage must be in the range between 0 and 100!");
        return;
    }

    updateBudgetAllocation(pib);
}
```

The problem is that the error message is not shown (I get no warning like "FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed").
I cannot figure out what's the problem with my code. Can someone help?

Comment: Try adding a <rich:messages globalOnly="true" /> or even without the globalOnly attribute (to show all not displayed messages) and check if it's still missing.

Comment: Yes with `<rich:messages/>` it shows up. But I need to display input specific messages, so I'd like to fix my code in order to use `<rich:message>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You add your message as a global error but you do not have any  element to display it.

What you want is not to add it as a global error message, but to attach it to the input-component which caused the error.

You can do it like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientId,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, errorMessage));
```

The important part here is the given clientId of the UIComponent. If you have this component (via binding for example) you can get it via UIComponent.getClientId(). (see [Retrieving other component's client ID in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124727/retrieving-other-components-client-id-in-jsf-2-0)).

If you do not have a reference to the component, the only chance you have is to analyze the whole component tree and search for it via the id you supplied with id="..." in the facelet file (.xhtml). (see [An efficient way to compute a UIComponent clientID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541245/an-efficient-way-to-compute-a-uicomponent-clientid))